# What is the difference in dev console vs fire base crash reporting

Tags: android, ios, firebase, crashlytics, crash-reports

I wanted to know if any one who is experienced with both App Store Connect & Google Play Developer Console what is the difference in the crash reporting logs it shows vs if you use say for instance firebase crash reporting(crashlytics) ? Is there any major difference ? I’m asking because I’m deciding if I should integrate firebase crash reporting in my app or if the crash logs it shows on the developer consoles (iOS&Android) would do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash reports in the app stores are very minimal as far as features go. Using something like crashlytics or any other analytics suite has much more tools and data points as well as other metrics that simply don't get reported in the app store reports.

Comment: Do you know some examples of the tools and data points they use ? Do you know if the App Store reports what methods or calls caused the crash ? I think if it does it should do the job for me but this will be my first app so I still don’t know yet how the reports look

Comment: I would just check out the documentation and compare your needs

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the GooglePlay Console and Crashlytics report different ANRs/crashes.

Status today, July 27th 2022 taking one of my apps as an example:

- the Play Console reports 4 crashes over the last 30 days. None of the 4 are visible on Crashlytics.
- on the other hand Crashlytics reports 2 ANRs and 1 crash over the last 30 days. Again these 3 incidents are not visible on the Play Store Console.

Conclusion: I'm afraid you will need both - and probably still won't be able to fully trust the reports